# db.sql to localhost

Tags: php, sql

I can't import my db sql to local host. Please help.

After I import my db, this happens:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `admins` (
    `id` SMALLINT( 5 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `username` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
    `password` VARCHAR( 32 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
    `email` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
    `firstname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
    `lastname` VARCHAR( 50 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
    `datereg` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    `lastlogin` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ,
    KEY  `username` (  `username` ) ,
    KEY  `password` (  `password` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =14;
```

MySQL said:

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

Please tell me what to do!

Here is my code:

```
$cfg['db_host']  = 'localhost';
$cfg['db_uname'] = 'root';
$cfg['db_pword'] = '';
$cfg['db_name']  = 'artofmine';
```

Please tell me what to change.

Comment: you have not selected database.. run the following query before you run this query.... use yourDatabaseName;

Comment: or change this  admins to artofmine.admins

Comment: @user1754526 See the `case1352` answer!

Answer (score 1):

run

```
use artofmine;
```

in your mysql gui or command line before you run the create statement

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't know in which database you want to work.

Write in SQL (before your query):

```
USE artofmine;
```

or specify database after connecting in PHP. Example:

```
<?php

// connect - make link
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// select database for that link
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('artofmine', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```